# How to disable port reuse when binding ServerSocket in Java8?

Tags: java, sockets, java-8, port, serversocket

I'm creating a `ServerSocket` in Java8 with `new ServerSocket(0)` to let Java select an available port for me. When testing, I sometimes discover that the client seems to have connected to the `ServerSocket`, but the `accept` method of `ServerSocket` did not return.

I print out the socket usage and discover that there are two processes using this port. The printed message is:

```
idea       857 (user)  (fd)  IPv4 (device)      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:49375 (LISTEN)
java      6878 (user)  (fd)  IPv6 (device)      0t0  TCP *:49375 (LISTEN)
```

As the bind address is different, `idea` and `java` can both listen on port `49375`. So I would like Java to not use a port another process is already using. `ServerSocket.setReuseAddress` is not useful because it only changes the reuse of a `TIMED_WAIT` port. I also discover that Java9 supports `SO_REUSEPORT` but I'm using Java8. Is there any method to achieve this?

Comment: I've run into the same problem and am hoping for an answer.